# Java AP Comp Sci OOP

Tags: java, oop

I'm having trouble understand when instantiations are valid in object oriented programming questions. This is my current thinking so far in pseudo. Is this correct?

if b extends a, b gets a's methods

```
a o = new b()  //BAD
b o = new a()  //GOOD


public class a{ public void Aa()  }
public class b extends a{ public void Bb()  }

a o = new a()
a.Bb()    //BAD

b o = new b()
b.Aa()    //GOOD

b o = new a()
b.Aa()   //GOOD
b.Bb()   //GOOD
```

Comment: Run it yourself and see....?

Comment: You're going to have to explain "BAD" for `a o = new b()  //BAD` case. Looks "GOOD" to me under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of subclasses as having an "is a" relationship with the parent class.  For example, if you have a class `Vehicle` and create a class `Car` that extends `Vehicle`, you can say "a Car is a Vehicle" but not "a Vehicle is a Car".

For assigning values to variables, you can assign a value to a variable if you can say the value being assigned "is a" value of the variable's type.  For example,

```
Vehicle v = new Car(); // valid because a Car "is a" Vehicle
Car c = new Vehicle(); // not valid because a Vehicle is not necessarily a Car.
```

Now apply the same reasoning to your case, where you have a `b` that extends an `a`, meaning that (a `b` "is a" `a`):

> a o = new b()  //BAD
>
> b o = new a()  //GOOD

The first one is actually good, because `b` "is a" `a`, in the same sense that a `Car` is a `Vehicle`.  The second one is actually bad, because not every `a` "is a" `b`, just like not every `Vehicle` "is a" `Car`.